# How to enable OpenGL extensions in AOSP？

Tags: android, android-source

As the title suggests, while browsing the color management content in Google's official documentation, I learned that a wide color gamut requires corresponding extensions to be enabled, but I have no idea. I request everyone's help.

enable OpenGL extensions，I need to build it during the compile process.